# Delay bluetooth permissions request for React Native on iOS

Tags: objective-c, react-native, bluetooth

Currently my app requests bluetooth permissions on first load via a custom Objective-C module that is exposed via RCT_EXPORT to React Native. The pseudo code below works correctly.

```objectivec
  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
  CBCentralManager *centralManager;
  CBManagerState bluetoothState = CBManagerStateUnknown;

  // Gets called during first load
  -(instancetype) init {
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    return self;
  }

  // Gets called correctly when permissions are set
  - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(nonnull CBCentralManager *)central {
    bluetoothState = central.state;
  }
```

However, I want to be able to request bluetooth permissions when I need the bluetooth functionality. It's possible to invoke the `initBluetooth()` method at the desired time, but the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` is not called:

```objectivec
  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
  CBCentralManager *centralManager;
  CBManagerState bluetoothState = CBManagerStateUnknown;

  // Get's called at the desired time, and OS settings are set correctly
  RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(initBluetooth: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()];
  }
  
  // No longer gets called
  - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(nonnull CBCentralManager *)central {
    bluetoothState = central.state;
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` is not invoked when initialising bluetooth via this custom function?